# Initialize a Mapbox map only when a user request to see a map, not on page load

Tags: javascript, html, mapbox

How can I initialize a Mapbox map on a webpage only when a user requests the map? Here is how it is done on page load according to the Mapbox docs:

```
<div id="map"></div>

<script>
mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.????';
var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
container: 'map',
style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11',
center: [ myLng  ,  myLat   ],
zoom: 14
});

var marker = new mapboxgl.Marker()
.setLngLat([myLng , myLat])
.addTo(map);
</script>
```

Is it possible to wrap the above in a function that I can call on some button or link click? If so how is it done?

Answer (score 1):

It worked when I changed the `onclick="showMap()"` to

```
var showMapBtn = document.getElementById("showMapBtn");
showMapBtn.addEventListener('click', showMap);
```

and I also added `event.preventDefault()` to my function.

Comment: Glad you have figured it out

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can take the content of the script and wrap it into function. Than you can call this function on button click.

```
<script>
function myMapClick(){
mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.????';
var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
container: 'map',
style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11',
center: [ myLng  ,  myLat   ],
zoom: 14
});

var marker = new mapboxgl.Marker()
.setLngLat([myLng , myLat])
.addTo(map);
}
</script>
```

And than somewhere in your body of the page you can put the code like

```
<button onclick="myMapClick()">Click me</button>
```

It's hard to help/test it without the working html but I hope this sorts out your concerns.

Comment: I did try that, but nothing happens when I call the function.

Comment: I thought too that maybe the variables have to be global, so I prefixed them with  `window.` and removed the `var` before the declaration but nothing really happens with this either. the html is very simple `<div id="map"></div>`, I will add it to the main question.

Comment: Does everything work without a function wraper?

Comment: Yes, the map initializes just fine without the function wrapper. And now it does so with the function wrapper, after the changes I mentioned above. Thank you.